# How to download maplotlib to use on python 3.6.1 shell on a mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, matplotlib

I am using a mac with OS Sierra and I just downloaded python 3.6.1 from python.org and have IDLE on my desktop.  On terminal I downloaded pip and a bunch of external programs like pandas and matplotlib.  I then created a new file in python and saved it to my desktop.  I imported datetime and imported matplotlib.pyplot as plt and ran the program under the python shell.  The output on the shell is "No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; matplotlib' is not a package.

Can I change the Python Launcher to alter the path or how can I add the matplotlib module to the downloaded python IDLE/shell.

Comment: When you run `python`, which version do you see in the terminal? I suspect it is running Python 2.7 or another version instead of Python 3.6 since 3.6 isn't the default

Comment: I am running Python 2.7 in terminal

Comment: How do I make Python 3.6 default then?

Comment: You probably don't want to as the operating system might be using Python 2.7 for something. Just run `python3` or `python3.6` in your terminal and it should work.